# Stack Overflow-esque source code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I am aware Stack Overflow isn't open source, but i have seen a MIX video of phil haack creating a Stack Overflow-like app called 'haackOverflow" . can anyone help me with the link to download its source code.

PS : I'm looking for a app that is developed in ASP.NET MVC(with best practices). i have found music store, nerd dinner,and MS town hall app.

Comment: No, this does **not** belong on meta; since this isn't *stackoverflow* source, it is general programming. Not meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the one you mention in your question, but I believe that it is what you are after...

http://stacked.ra-ajax.org/

http://code.google.com/p/stacked/

Don't be too put off by the style of their demo - look at the feature set and imagine your own design!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an Open Source StackOverflow-like site **LampCMS**. It has many features similar to SO and many featuers similar to Quora. It's written in php 5.3 and powered by MongoDB. It is very fast and can handle very high-traffic sites on a relatively inexpensive server and can easily scale horizontally to very large multi-server implementation.

Source code on gitgub.

Demo: **http://support.lampcms.com**